# Nodejs array filter and modify

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have to apply complex buisness logic on api data. There is one step where I have to traverse through the array of user objects and apply some condition if users object matches that condition we have to add a key in every object. And use the new array.

1. How we can do this efficiently without for loop. Is there any function in es6 Because I want to modify and filter  array at the same time and return new array.
2. If there is no way other than for loop how to stop executing return statement to execute before for loop complete so that I can return new array.

Comment: "more efficient without for loop" is not possible. And if the `return` is after the loop, it will `return` after the loop!

Comment: Reduce, Map, Filter, Some and all of these fancy new methods are just abstracting the for loop, there is no way around it. Your function will always return whenever you hit a return statement and it will return whatever the value is that comes immediately after your return statement. If you want to stop executing the loop but continue executing the function use break.

Comment: @JonasW. When I am doing asynchronous operation and storing result in new array. Return after for loop executed before for loop

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't tell what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't do this efficiently without using for loops. Even if you use some library function it will still use the loop internally, so don't worry about that.
2. If you don't want to execute `return` statement before for loop completes then don't put return statement inside for loop; use `break/continue` instead. And when the for loop completes return the new array.